# Dpkg error E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg

I can't upgrade my ubuntu 18.04
Here is the log,

```
Fetched 427 MB in 45s (9,542 kB/s)                                             
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 1 expected program not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

I tried every solution I've found googling but didn't work.

```
echo $PATH
Output: /home/bs204/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin

which start-stop-daemon
No output

Output cat /etc/sudoers

#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    mail_badpass
Defaults    secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: `echo $PATH`; Output: `/home/bs204/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/dart/bin`
`which start-stop-daemon`; No output

Comment: `cat /etc/sudoers` please. edit your question for output. thank's.

Comment: start-stop-daemon is provided by the `dpkg` package. Try reinstalling that package: `sudo apt install --reinstall dpkg`. It's very unusual for an application to simply vanish...it's usually a clue that something else important has happened.

Comment: Can't reinstall dpkg through `sudo apt install --reinstall dpkg`. It shows same error.

Comment: @nobody Edited the question with the output of `cat /etc/sudoers`. Please check now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a solution to my question.

```
sudo -i
mkdir /tmp
mkdir /tmp/dpkg
cd /tmp/dpkg
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dpkg/dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
ar -x dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb
tar -xf data.tar.xz
cp ./sbin/start-stop-daemon /sbin
```

If dpkg broken:

```
cp ./usr/bin/dpkg /usr/bin/
apt update 
apt install --reinstall dpkg
apt upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

Thank you, that helps me to fix my problem:

```
  dpkg: warning:  'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
```

One addition to your good solution:
On my OMV-System i don't have "ar" so I use the command

```
"dpkg-deb -x dpkg_1.19.7ubuntu1_amd64.deb ."
```